# Change the direction of a new client appearance in Awesome Window Manager

Tags: awesome, rc

In previous releases of Awesome WM new client title appeared to the right from the previous client. So, client titles were ordered from left to right by their order of appearance.

In new releases of Awesome this order has reversed. Quit naggingly, each new client title appears to the left from the old client.

How to make such that title for each new client will appear to the right from old client?

Example: There is a single client --internet browser -- opened in a current workspace. I press MODKey+Enter and, irrespectively of windows layout, title of terminal client appears to the left from the title of the internet browser. Personally for me it would make much more sense if this new terminal title would be to the right from old browser title.

Answer (score 9):

In `rc.lua` uncomment line 

`if not awesome.startup then awful.client.setslave(c) end`

Comment: Lifesaver! That behavior was so annoying. How'd you find that solution? Love awesome, but configuration requires quite a bit of study!

Comment: Only problem with this solution is that new windows are "little tiles" in any layouts that have big and little titles (is that the master/slave terminology?). Is there a way to affect how the layouts order the windows?